# ASP.NET Core API Service Lifetime

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I have a service in my ASP.NET Core (2.1) app that needs to be a singleton, as I have information that I need to keep in memory over the entire lifetime of the app. This service has dependencies to some repositories that do not need to be singletons and I would like to define them as transient, but ASP.NET Core does not like it when you inject a transient dependency into a singleton service. I can kind of understand why, though I'm still new to this stuff. But my question is: what is the correct way to handle this situation? I can just make my repositories singletons and that will satisfy ASP.NET Core. Or I could try using a service provider to get the repositories just when they're needed. But I'm looking for a "best practices" approach. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: A singleton by definition is always instantiated once.  How do you imagine you could inject transient constructor arguments?  Transient services `"are created each time they're requested"` with a singleton they will only ever be requested once

Comment: Perhaps you can add some information about the service? So we can suggest a more appropriate approach

Comment: "ASP.NET Core does not like it when you inject a transient dependency into a singleton service". Why is that? To my knowledge, ASP.NET Core is completely fine with this approach? Are you getting an exception of any sort? If so, please post the exception details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @CamiloTerevinto indicated in the comments, it's difficult to give you precise guidance without knowing more about what you're actually doing. I can tell you some general things, though.

First, singletons come in two forms: things that are so simplistic there's no point in having multiple copies or things that are so complex it would be burdensome to have multiple copies. Anything on the spectrum in between should likely be request-scoped or transient. Importantly, keeping data in-memory, is *not* a valid reason to use singleton scope. You can use memory cache (or even better: distributed cache) from a object with *any* lifetime. needing long-lived state on an object is pretty much always a signal of bad class design.

Second, ironically, if anything, your repositories should actually be the ones with a singleton scope. A repository generally requires a database connection and that should be as long-lived as possible or practical.

However, don't just go ahead an make your repositories singletons and call it a day. You should stop first and evaluate if your current singleton class really should in fact be in that scope. Then, depending on your application, it might actually be better to have the repos request-scoped, which still means you can't inject them directly.

Comment: just a small comment: repos should actually have dependency on some dbcontext (which holds db connection) which means dbcontext should be singleton and repositories themselves can be transient | scoped (probably transient as they are stateless).

Comment: No. A repository should not have a dependency on a `DbContext` because you shouldn't even be using a repository in that case. The only valid use of the repository pattern is when dealing with low-level data access, such as direct SQL queries. An ORM like Entity Framework *is* your data layer.

Comment: hm, that's pretty hard to imagine. real world example: you have ddd project and cosmosdb where you store your data. you don't use any orm. you have repositories (defined as interfaces in domain). cosmosdb client connection should be singleton. how would you do that if not injecting dbClient into your repository implementation?

Comment: This application is a "server" application that is getting data by making web calls to various in-house machines, so using a dbcontext is not an issue in this case. I see what you're saying about using a cache instead. I believe that currently, maintaining the data in memory is the only reason for making the service a singleton. I will take another look at it and see if I can use a cache instead. Thanks!

Comment: @deezg The db client then is your "connection". In such a scenario, you're just using the cosmosdb client instead of ADO.NET's SqlClient. Same diff. That is fine. However, if you have an ORM. That ORM is your data layer. It makes absolutely zero sense to wrap it in yet another repository layer, and actually just increases the entropy of your application.

Comment: @ChrisPratt i agree completely. i was talking about non-orm case. not sure actually where orm case came from :)